# PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY to my table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, mysql-workbench

So im trying to add an primary key and a foreign key to my table, but i just can't seem to get it to work. i've checked the forums already and other places but it didn't answer my problem. So here is my table:

http://puu.sh/mVW7D/5986e08daa.png
im trying to get VeiederID as my foreing key and keep studentnr as primary

but ive tryied to "alter table" and add the foreing key as constraint, but i might be doing it wrong, im very new to mysql. any help is appirciated

Comment: Need to see the "alter table" you're running.  One thing to remember is that the table that is being referred to has to exist already.  You can't create a foreign key constraint referencing a table that does not exist.

Comment: I deleted my "alter table" and the only thing that is in my script now is this table and info to the my values that a defined in the table. I just dont get how i can add the foreign element to this

Comment: I updated the answer but it still may take some work.

Comment: thanks, i'll try it bit with this. Much appreciated for your help

Comment: i uploaded a new pic in "answer" and i think i might have figured it out

Comment: you should make "index" the column which you want to make foreign key.

Comment: do you have an example on how to do that?

Comment: i am using "phpmyadmin". i just click index and then add foreign key with help of the GUI. So idk how to index with coding. However i am sure you have to index it before adding a foreign key. Sorry for not helping

Answer (score 0):

Steffen

Two points:

1. You do not identify the second table. A foreign key works between two tables and you are only showing one.
2. You do not specify which `mysql` version you are using.

Regardless: You should read the manual, reference: [v 5.7 Foreign Keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

**Update**

I see from your updated example you are creating 3 tables and you want the rows in `Veileder` to reference `studentinfo`. So, the statement in the `Veiled` table should be

```
FOREIGN KEY (VeilederID) 
        REFERENCES studentinfo(VeiederID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Apologies if the spelling is wrong. One other note, it appears you are trying to make the primary key (VeilederID) map to the foreign key. If I am wrong please comment but I don't know if that would be allow. Typically a table HAS it's own primary and a reference constrain (a.k.a. FOREIGN KEY) as a different column.

Comment: updated it now. And yes i did read that, but i couldn't figure out how to implement it to my script. Im a big noob on mysql

Answer (score -1):

think i found it now i dont get an error while im running it this way, but if its right im not sure..

http://puu.sh/mW1Ze/ae333a40d6.png